# Rails - How to Pass Params Across Two Domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app needs to use two domains.  How can I save parameters appearing on one of the domains and redirect to the other domain with those parameters?  Also, the values of the parameters will always be changing.

```
domain1.com?param1=true

redirects to

domain2.com?param1=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best option would be to handle all domains on upstream web server (like nginx) and proxy the request to one application without the need to handle redirects directly in Rails application.

Something like

```
server {
  server_name .mydomain.com;
  rewrite ^ http://www.adifferentdomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

If you still need to perform redirect on the Rails side you can do it using `redirect_to` (at least if you can always say which one of the domains is the target one).

```
redirect_to root_url(host: "adifferentdomain.com", params: request.parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be of some help

```
request.original_fullpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.  I ended up writing an action that simply creates the new URL w/ the params as a string and redirects:

```
def stripe_redirect
        subdomain = request.subdomain
        if subdomain == 'secure'
            params = request.original_fullpath.split("?").second
            new_url = "http://www.newdomain.com/auth/stripe_connect/callback?" << params
            redirect_to new_url
        end
    end
```